# Where can I find climb and cruise performance charts for a specific aircraft?

Tags: performance-calculation

I'm looking for climb and cruise charts for a cirrus sr20 G3, but I can't find them in the POH?  where are these charts typically located?

Comment: Does the SR20 come with a separate Air Crew Manual or perhaps a Performance Manual? I would normally expect to find such information in Section 5 of the POH, otherwise. [full disclosure: I've never checked out in a Cirrus]

Comment: You generally only find that kind of stuff in transport category airplane pubs where there is a performance engineering organization to create the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about the Cirrus SR 20 (G3), but here is a manual that has Performance charts in section 5:

[[PILOT’S OPERATING HANDBOOK
AND FAA APPROVED
AIRPLANE FLIGHT MANUAL
for the
CIRRUS DESIGN SR20][1](http://PILOT%E2%80%99S%20OPERATING%20HANDBOOK%20AND%20FAA%20APPROVED%20AIRPLANE%20FLIGHT%20MANUAL%20for%20the%20CIRRUS%20DESIGN%20SR20)](http://www.flymaa.org/assets/cirrus-sr20-poh.pdf)

Here is a sample chart:

[image]

Hope it helps.